# Display UIAlertController at bottom xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I required alert showing at bottom of screen in iOS, as of now it is displaying in middle of screen. Alert I am dismissing after few seconds.

The code below I am using

```
void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
{
    alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, (obj) =>
    {
        dismissMessage();
    });
    alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
}
```

How can I make its position to bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> alert showing at bottom of screen in iOS

You want to use a style of "ActionSheet"

```
var alert = UIAlertController.Create("StackOverflow", "Rocks", UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);
```

Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/action-sheets/

[image]

Comment: Wow! It looks beautiful, Can't I make little up?